# Jest: toThrow() matcher

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, promise, jestjs, throw

Context: React application with mobx.

Anyway I've a class (a store), **catalogStore**,  with a **loadProducts** method. This method call a service to get the data and then, return it.

I've to write a test that say "If it cannot get the data, then throw an exception"

I mocked the function supposed to get the data, forcing it to reject... ok

This is the test I wrote

```
describe("catalogStore", () => {
  describe("if the catalog fails to get the data", () => {
    beforeAll(() => {
      catalogService.get = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          reject("rejected error");
        });
      });
    });

    it("should throw an error", () => {
      return expect(() => catalogStore.loadProducts()).toThrow();
    });
  });
});
```

And this is the loadProducts function:

```
loadProducts() {
  return catalogService
    .get()
    .then(result => {
      this.products = result.services;
      return {products: this.products};
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log("CatalogStore loadProducts error catch: ", error);
      return { error };
    })
    .then(({ error }) => {
      if (error) {
        console.log("Im gonna throw the error -> ", error);
        throw error;
      }
    });
}
```

From the logs I can see "Im gonna throw the error -> rejected error", but the test fails with this message:

> Expected the function to throw an error. But it didn't throw anything.

Why? I'm throwing the error.

Luca

Answer (score 2):

Your error is thrown in the context of a Promise chain callback. It will be caught by the Promise and passed to the next [catch handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch).

To modify your test to inspect the error you could use [Jest's Promise expectations](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/expect.html#rejects):

```
describe("catalogStore", () => {
  describe("if the catalog fails to get the data", () => {
    beforeAll(() => {
      catalogService.get = jest.fn().mockImplementation(() => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          reject("rejected error");
        });
      });
    });

    it("should throw an error", () => {
      return expect(catalogStore.loadProducts()).rejects.toThrow('rejected error');
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Its cause the function returns a promise, so all jest see is that the `get()` function is the  called but as the error happens in a promise the test is finished before the error is thrown. To test that promises have look on how [async error handling](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/tutorial-async.html#error-handling) works.

Main idea is that you have an async function where you catch the failing promises by yourself

```
it('fails', async()=>{
  try{
    await catalogStore.loadProducts()
  } catch(e) {
    expect(e).toBeDefined()
  }
})
```

Comment: If loadProducts succeeds this test will pass either way, when it is expected to fail. The above answer is correct using rejects.